# Delocalization of eigenvectors in Expanding Graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, expanders

Given an adjacency matrix $A$, can we say something about whether the eigenvectors corresponding to its highest (or second-highest) eigenvalues are de-localized ?

By de-localization I mean that every coordinate in the vector has nearly the same absolute value. Are there existing results regarding this for expanders?